# Lee Mosher book definition of a tree.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, free-groups

I was just reading the definition of a tree in Lee Mosher book, and he said if graph is simply connected then it is contractible.

I am wondering how is this true, can someone explain this to me please?Is there a proof for this fact?

**Edit:**

It seems like my question was not clear, here is what exactly I am asking,  any simply connected graph is a tree,I know a priori  that any tree is contractible.

Comment: In the book it is proved in section $1.2.2$ that every tree is contractible, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982424/trees-are-contractible).

Comment: Presumably it also needs to be connected, but maybe that's part of the definition.

Comment: I want it for a graph not a tree @DietrichBurde maybe I should edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, from your title it seems that you want a tree and not a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a maximal spanning tree $T$ of the graph $\mathscr{G}$. You hopefully know that, by one possible definition, $T$ is contractible, and also that $\pi_1(\mathscr{G})$ is freely generated by all edges in $E(\mathscr{G})\setminus E(T)$. So if the graph is simply connected there can be no such edges, and $\mathscr{G}=T$ is contractible.

For details see Hatcher's discussion of fundamental groups of graphs.

Comment: why there can be no such edges?

Comment: @Brain Because I said $\pi_1(\mathscr{G})$ is generated by those edges. As $\pi_1=0$ by hypothesis, there cannot be any such edges

Comment: I want to prove that any simply connected graph is a tree, maybe I should state this clearly in my question.

Comment: @Brain Ok, and I've done that. The tree exists, and we prove by simple-connectivity that there cannot be any difference between the tree $T$ and the graph $\mathscr{G}$! So $\mathscr{G}=T$ is a tree and is contractible

Comment: how do we know that $\pi_1$ of the graph is freely generated by all the edges in the graph? Is this a lemma in Hatcher?

Comment: Why do we need a maximal tree and not just a tree?

Comment: @Brain (To the first) Yes it's in Hatcher, I leave those details for Hatcher. Why we need a maximal tree is also in Hatcher, essentially. Because $T$ is maximal it is fairly easy to calculate $\pi_1(\mathscr{G})\cong\pi_1(\mathscr{G}/T)$, because $\mathscr{G}/T$ has only one vertex

Comment: I thought this quotient does not have any vertex, since the maximal tree has all the vertices of a graph,  am I correct?

Comment: @Brain There is a very important difference between $\mathscr{G}\setminus T$ and $\mathscr{G}/T$. In the (topological) quotient $\mathscr{G}/T$ we, in particular, identify all the vertices of $T$ so essentially send them to one vertex, and because all vertices of $\mathscr{G}$ are in $T$ that means all vertices of $\mathscr{G}$ get identified to one vertex. They don't get *removed*; they get glued together

Comment: Thank you very much!